# Ldap client cant connect with local server

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, dnsmasq

I am trying to setup an openldap server But it is not able to connect with client. I have configured dnsmasq properly

client configuration /etc/ldap/ldap.conf

```
BASE    dc=openldap,dc=lan
URI     ldap://172.31.xx.xxx
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost openldap.lan
127.0.1.1  openldap.lan
172.31.xx.xxx   public.openldap.lan
```

But ldapsearch -x is returning with result: 32 No such object. I have already checked all answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38430385/result-32-no-such-object 
But none of them working.

Comment: I assume the OpenLDAP server is on localhost. Can you add slapd configuration: `ldapsearch -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=config '(objectClass=olcDatabaseConfig)'` (run as root, remove the `olcPW` attribute).

Comment: thanks Piotr P Karwasz. I figured it out actually there was a white space there. I wasn't aware that ldap configuration is whitespace sensitive. I forget to put here in case it helps any beginner.